# Incorrect generation of changelog in Liquibase - No function matches... You might need to add explicit type casts.(liquibase + spring.boot)

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, changelog

I used the generate the command - **changeLogcommand**, to upload the data, and use the resulting file as a changelog.

```sh
liquibase generateChangeLog
```

I use **Spring boot 2.4.1**

I use **PostgreSql 11.x**

- db.changelog-master.xml

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="db/changelog/xml/db/changelog-1.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="IT (generated)" id="1609684188168-1">
        <createTable remarks="Aircrafts (internal data)" tableName="aircrafts_data">
            <column name="aircraft_code" remarks="Aircraft code, IATA" type="CHAR(3)">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="aircrafts_pkey"/>
            </column>
            <column name="model" remarks="Aircraft model" type="JSONB">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="range" remarks="Maximal flying distance, km" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="IT (generated)" id="1609684188168-2">

....

    <changeSet author="IT (generated)" id="1609684188168-9">
        <createView fullDefinition="false" remarks="Aircrafts" viewName="aircrafts">SELECT ml.aircraft_code,
            (ml.model -&gt;&gt; lang()) AS model,
            ml.range
            FROM aircrafts_data ml;</createView>
    </changeSet>

...
```

- pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

Then I would like to apply the resulting file to the created project. But an error appears on startup.

> Caused by: liquibase. exception.Migration Failed Exception: migration
> failed for dB/change set / in XML format/dB / change-1. XML module::
> 1609684188168-9: yes (automatically): Reason: liquibase. exception.
> DatabaseException: ERROR: the lang () function does not exist Hint: No
> function matches the specified name and argument types. You may need
> to add explicit type casts. Position: 84 [not in SQL: (0) creating a
> public view.aircraft, how to select ml. aircraft_code, (ml. model - >
>
> > lang()) as the ml. range model From aircraft_data ml;]

- lang

```sql
create function lang() returns text
    stable
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN current_setting('bookings.lang');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN undefined_object THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;

alter function lang() owner to postgres;
```

As I understand it, the generator could not also transfer the function to changelog.xml, as well as views.

When I used that

- liquibase.properties

```sql
diffTypes:catalog,tables,functions,views,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints,data,storedprocedure,triggers,sequences
```

I have got the errors:

> [2021-01-03 18:51:02] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Unexpected error
> running Liquibase: Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
> heap space
> at java.base/java.lang.StringUTF16.compress(StringUTF16.java:160)
> at java.base/java.lang.String.(String.java:3214)
> at java.base/java.lang.String.(String.java:276)
> at org.postgresql.core.OptimizedUTF8Encoder.charDecode(OptimizedUTF8Encoder.java:71)
> at org.postgresql.core.ByteOptimizedUTF8Encoder.decode(ByteOptimizedUTF8Encoder.java:27)
> at org.postgresql.core.Encoding.decode(Encoding.java:252)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1910)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.internalGetObject(PgResultSet.java:197)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getObject(PgResultSet.java:2577)
> at liquibase.util.JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(JdbcUtils.java:80)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.core.MissingDataChangeGenerator.fixMissing(MissingDataChangeGenerator.java:92)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorChain.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorChain.java:48)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorFactory.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorFactory.java:95)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets(DiffToChangeLog.java:302)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.printNew(DiffToChangeLog.java:226)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog$1.run(DiffToChangeLog.java:133)
> at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
> at liquibase.Scope$$Lambda$42/0x00000008000ecc40.run(Unknown Source)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:127)
> at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:85)
> at liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:74)
> at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:249)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1519)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:361)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1$$Lambda$41/0x00000008000ec840.run(Unknown
> Source)
> at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
> at liquibase.Scope$$Lambda$42/0x00000008000ecc40.run(Unknown Source)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)

Then I removed the - **data** type. The file was generated without errors (**data** -had to be deleted. The error was possible due to the fact that it was necessary to check a large amount of data).

But I still don't see the - **lang()** function there.

As I understand it, there should be something like: **create function**...

I assume that you need to get a pro license, because the **'creation function'** is available in the pro version.

Then I used **pro version**.

Now I have got another errors:

> rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
> bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.io.IOException:
> createFunction path=objects/function/lang-bcd8b0c2.sql> -Unable to
> read file

How can I configure the generation to avoid such errors in the future, and how can I fix it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it's just a workaround. I just couldn't get liquibase to create a separate schema and import everything there.

- master.xml

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="xml/changelog-2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="xml/changelog-3.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="xml/changelog-4.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

- changelog-2.xml

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="IT" id="1609692217402-1">
        <sqlFile path="db/changelog/sql/langFunction.sql" splitStatements="false"/>
    </changeSet>


    <changeSet author="IT" id="1609692217402-2">
        <sqlFile path="db/changelog/sql/nowFunction.sql" splitStatements="false"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

- langFunction.sql

```sql
create function lang() returns text
    stable
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN current_setting('lang');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN undefined_object THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;

alter function lang() owner to postgres;
```

**Views** must also be started after the functions and tables are created